# make alpha variable in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a timeseries dataframe. I would like to plot the dataframe then shade out periods where the value is below 10, and leave the periods above 10 unshaded.

Attempt 1: 
I have tried to do this with geom_ribbon() - reproducible code is shown below.  As you can see however, the periods shaded are not correct.

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot)
Data <- data.frame(
value = sample(1:21),
Year = seq(1990, 2010, 1))

ggplot(Data, aes(Year)) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = -Inf,
                  ymax = Inf, 
                 fill = ifelse(value>=10, 'Not shaded', 'Shaded')),
              alpha = 0.3)+
 geom_line(aes(Year, value))+
 scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'NA'))
```

[image]

Attempt 2:
I also tried to do this by reading in the alpha (alpha = 0 when value is above 10 and alpha = 1 when value is above 10). This gave me the error:

> Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `geom_rect` instead, where it shades each year based on the test. Note, I swapped the fill orders, and that `scale_fill_manual` first fills `FALSE` since it comes alphabetically earlier, even though it's defined 2nd in the `ifelse`.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(Year)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Year - 0.5,
                xmax = Year + 0.5, 
                ymin = -Inf,
                  ymax = Inf, 
                  fill = ifelse(value < 10,  'Shaded',  'Not shaded')),
              alpha = 0.3)+
  geom_line(aes(Year, value))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('NA', 'blue'), name = "Year")
```

[image]